# Add detail message to ASP.NET Core 3.1 standard JSON BadRequest response

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, bad-request

I have a controller in my ASP.NET Core 3.1 app that returns `BadRequest()` in one of the cases.
By default it produces the json response:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "|492dbc28-4cf485d536d40917."
}
```

Which is awesome, but I'd like to add a `detail` string value with a specific message.

When I return `BadRequest("msg")`, the response is a plain text `msg`.

When I do it this way `BadRequest(new { Detail = "msg" })`, the response is a json:

```
{
  "detail": "msg"
}
```

Which is better, but I'd like to preserve the original json data as well.

My goal is to return this kind of response:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "detail": "msg",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "|492dbc28-4cf485d536d40917."
}
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The [ControllerBase.Problem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.problem) method is a perfect fit for this. Here's an example that produces the desired response:

```
public IActionResult Post()
{
    // ...

    return Problem("msg", statusCode: (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

Here's an example of the output, for completeness:

```
{
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "msg",
  "traceId": "|670244a-4707fe3038da8462."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the Json data in typed object and send this response back.

```
class MyClass
{
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string traceId { get; set; }
    public string detail { get; set; }
}
```

Convert your Json data with this class Type and add the detail message in `detail` field.

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(yourJson);
obj.detail = "msg";
```

Comment: @Sergey the answer useful for you in any way or not? Did your work is done?

Comment: Where do I get `yourJson`? I don't have it, it's generated by the framework somewhere under the hood.

Comment: It would receive, probably, from any API response? Isn't it ?

Comment: No, that is not the case. The response doesn't have any data, it just has to return a Bad Request result.